# изменить шаблон окна <input type="color">

Tags: html, css

Есть ли какой нибудь способ изменить стилевые параметры всплывающего окна input type="color" или же полностью заменить шаблон.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрим одну из библиотек - Tiny jQuery colorPicker (http://www.dematte.at/tinyColorPicker/) Готовое решение http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPrMGQ

```
<input value="#B6BD79" id="color" style="background-color: rgb(95, 104, 16); color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PitPik/tinyColorPicker/master/jqColorPicker.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.color').colorPicker(); // that's it
</script>
```

Библиотек для выбора цвета большое множество, вот список jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-color-picker/

Comment: Еще один пример evol.colorpicker (https://github.com/evoluteur/colorpicker) Посмотреть тут http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZVLMw